# How can I put Voronoi/Thiessen polygons on Google Maps for free with no programming knowledge?

Tags: voronoi-thiessen

The only thing anywhere close to what I describe in the title is this site: http://lpetrich.org/Science/GeometryDemo/GeometryDemo_GMap.html. It has a couple problems, though: 1. There is no easy to way to preserve whatever map one makes and 2. Sometimes, if two points are too close together the border between them will be obviously off-center.

I just want to play around with this function. I lack the commercial motives or technical knowledge to buy or use ArcGIS. I can find free map tools online that allow me to find latitudes and longitudes and measure distances between two points: Why can't I find a way to make a Voronoi diagram?

Comment: Do you really want to know why you can't find it? Or do you have a question that could have a positive answer. I'd suggest taking the tour (see link in top right) and then editing your question. Personally, I think investigating QGIS might be useful for you, if you haven't already investigated that.

Comment: You're looking for the surprisingly powerful https://d3js.org/ -- it's advertised as primarily a cosmetic tool but does much much more. Sample use: http://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/5610671